# Does overfitting imply an upper bound on model size/complexity?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting

Suppose that I have a model M that overfits a large dataset S such that the test error is 30%. Does that mean that there will always exist a model that is smaller and less complex than M that will have a test error less than 30% on S (and does not overfit S).

Comment: If you want to discuss theoretical bounds, you should probably define a few more terms. Such as relative size of test and train sets, what counts as over-fitting in numerical terms (100% accuracy on training data - or something else?) If overfitting is 100%, the training and test data are drawn from the same distribution and test set is smaller, then you should be able to construct a smaller model which 100% fits the test data - such a model probably exists, but it would be very unlikely to be reachable by training on the training data. That seems trivial - is it what you are looking for?

Comment: What exactly you mean by less complex?

Comment: @NeilSlater for now I only wanted an intuitive explanation. But it would be interesting to have some sort of theoretical bound. Could you point me to some resources that discuss these theoretical bounds?

Comment: @DuttaA for now I am using the term complexity quite loosely. Here I mean the size of the model/number of parameters it has.